# Showing all the results of a loop with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, loops

Im lost. Im new to javascript/jQuery. I've made this loop to loop through JSON stuff:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var geturl = "http://couponsforweed.com/?json=get_recent_posts";

            $.ajax({

                type:'GET',
                url:geturl,
                complete: function(){                    
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    var response = data; //JSON.parse(data);

                    // it works!
                    alert("status: " + response.status + "\ncount: " + response.count + "\npages: " + response.pages + "\ncount_total: " + response.count_total + "\nposts: " + response.posts.length);


                    //loop through posts
                    for(var i = 0; i != response.posts.length; i++) {

                        //get each element in the array
                        var post = response.posts[i];


                        // output stuff so we can see things
                        output.innerHTML = i + " post: " + post.custom_fields.schemaState;

                    }


                },
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {                    
                    alert("Error");

                }

            });
  </script>
```

It works, Im pleased with myself for getting that to work. But heres my problem:

```
// output stuff so we can see things
   output.innerHTML = i + " post: " + post.custom_fields.schemaState;
```

How come this only gives me the last result in the loop and not a list of all the results in the loop?

I get:

9 Ca

I would like to see (each result in the loop):

1 Ca
2 Ca
3 Ca
4 Ca
5 Co
6 Wa
7 Co
8 Ca
9 Ca

Im used to PHP loops in WordPress where you can cycle though all the fields of each post and get the results accordingly.

Comment: You're assigning the string to the same `.innerHTML` property over and over again. Each iteration of the loop un-does what the previous iteration did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting output.innerHTML each time, effectively removing the results of previous iterations. Instead of:

```
output.innerHTML = i...
```

simply use:

```
output.innerHTML += i...
```

to append to the variable rather that set it. A better choice though would be to create an interim variable. For example if you named it foo:

```
foo += i...
```

each iteration, then at the end of the loop:

```
output.innerHTML = foo
```

This would be significantly more efficient as it only updates the DOM once at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should append with a "+=" instead of a "=" at:

```
output.innerHTML = i + " post: " + post.custom_fields.schemaState;
```

So it looks like

```
output.innerHTML += i + " post: " + post.custom_fields.schemaState;
```